# get screen size for iphone 6 simulator incorrect

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode6

I am working on a very old Iphone App, which we recently migrated to iOS 8. We are using

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

To get screen size but for **iphone 6 simulator** it is returning **568x320** for landscape mode.We have 3 launch images **Default, Default - 568h** and **Default**. Can somebody please let me the naming convention for adding a new launch image for Iphone 6.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may be helpful to you.

```
CGRect rect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

It will return you proper size.
And Splash screen Name is :

```
iphone 4/4s : Default@2x.png
iphone 5/5s : Default-568@2x.png
iphone 6    : Default-667h@2x.png
iphone 6plus:Default-736h@2x.png
```

Comment: But How do I add these splash images for iphone 6 and above?

Comment: You get this from  Project->Target->App Icons and Launch Image->Lauch Image Source.
Another path is:
Images.xcassets->Luach Image

Answer (score 0):

If you use an asset catalog for your launch images the full set of sizes are enumerated for you, and you don't have to worry about file naming conventions.[image]

Comment: You could also use a launch xib for newer devices.

Comment: I tried to add the splash image to asset catalogs but still it was giving incorrect size, then I deleted the asset catalog, but size was still incorrect. Is there any other way to add the splash screens to project in xcode 6?

Comment: In the project's setting you need to make sure that the Launch Image is set to the one you've made correctly.